# how to deploy octobercms projects on subdomains

Tags: laravel, .htaccess, subdomain, octobercms

I want to upload an OctoberCMS project to my subdomain on my site but it gives me 500 or 404 errors.

I changed *.htaccess* file multiple times but it didn't work.
E.g. I added these lines to the *.htaccess* file of my *public_html* folder:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^cms
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ cms/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Can anyone tell me what to do step by step to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at your Apache error logs. This might have nothing to do with OctoberCMS. It could be that mod_rewrite isn't enabled or don't have the proper AllowOverride rules set. Let us know what your Apache error logs say and we can help more.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks To you, I checked host settings, I figured out that problem was coming from Php Options.
first of all, I increase max_execution_time value and enable PDO for database settings then I create the .htaccess file in Public_html and problem was fixed!

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^cms
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ cms/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```